# Dreamweaver insert row then go to the detail page

Tags: php, insert

I'm using Dreamweaver as I'm still learning PHP.

I have an insert form and I want it to direct me to the detail page for the record just inserted. I have done this in the past but, have forgotten how I did it, I passed a url parameter with the record ID and picked it up on the detail page.

Here's my insert code, any help would be great.

```
if ((isset($_POST["MM_insert"])) && ($_POST["MM_insert"] == "form")) {
  $insertSQL = sprintf("INSERT INTO tl_courses (course_name, course_type, course_category, price_option, price, start_date, duration, location_option, country, region, town, postcode, results, awarding, content, requirements, additional, qualification) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)",
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['course_name'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['course_type'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['course_category'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['price_option'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['price'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['start_date'], "date"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['duration'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['location_option'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['country'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['region'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['town'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['postcode'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['results'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['awarding'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['content'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['requirements'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['additional'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['qualification'], "text"));

  mysql_select_db($database_dbconnect, $dbconnect);
  $Result1 = mysql_query($insertSQL, $dbconnect) or die(mysql_error());

  $insertGoTo = "dates_adder.php";
  if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
    $insertGoTo .= (strpos($insertGoTo, '?')) ? "&" : "?";
    $insertGoTo .= $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
  }
  header(sprintf("Location: %s", $insertGoTo));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you know the ID of the record you've just inserted? If not, you'll need to write a SELECT query to get the ID then just use:

To get the ID, either use mysql_insert_id() or write a query such as:

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM tl_courses WHERE course_name = "'.$_POST['course_name'].'"';
$res = mysql_query($sql);
$num = mysql_num_rows($res);

if($num == 1){
    // We've got a record.

    $row = mysql_fetch_array($res, MYSQL_ASSOC);

    $id  = $row['YOUR_ID_FIELD'];

}

header('Location: view.php?id='.$id);
exit;
```

Comment: Thanks, I don't know how to retrieve the ID as it would be a new record, I assume I would have to SELECT the ID with the highest number or something.

Comment: Well you can use the mysql_insert_id() but if your running a high traffic site and there's already another insert taken place then you may get the wrong record. I've added a possible SQL query to my answer.

Comment: Thanks again, does the select just get all the records? because there will be course_name duplicates.

Comment: Well in your where statement you will need to make it unique so it gets that record you only just created.

Comment: In your insert you could maybe add the timestamp of when the record was created and then use that timestamp in your WHERE clause

Comment: Again that might be a problem as adding records will be available to more than one user so, unlikely but they might add a record right at the same time. This is harder than I first thought :(

Comment: Ok you could also add the microtime() on the end of timestamp to make it even more unique.

Comment: OK thanks for the help, I'm sure I'll figure something out with this head start :)

Answer (score 2):

You will need to use

[mysql_insert_id();](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php)

in your code you can add this:

```
<?php 
// other code
$Result1 = mysql_query($insertSQL, $dbconnect) or die(mysql_error());

$id = mysql_insert_id();

$insertGoTo = "dates_adder.php?id=".$id;
header('Location: '.$insertGoTo);
?>
```

:)

Comment: MYSQLi...   that function is not recommended. 
use http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php